# Is physical NIC being recognized or is what I'm seeing a virtual NIC?

Tags: hyper-v

I'm running Hyper-V 2008R2 server. Everything was working fine until I decided to change the connection type from Internal Only to External. I mention this, so when I tell you the problem you don't think it's a NIC driver issue.

I used the MMC Hyper-V Managment plug-in to set the network connection type to external and I selected "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter". I also entered the Name as "Virtual Office NIC". The action did not complete cleanly and I lost connectivity to the Hyper-V server host.

When I go to the server and select item (8) Network Settings, I no longer see the physical NIC, but I see the name "Virtual Office NIC".

Did I hose my physical NIC? Or did the Hyper-V Manager simply write a string to the physical card's BIOS? That is, am what I seeing at the server, a renamed physical NIC or a new virtual NIC.

Since I've disabled the physical NIC in the server's setup I assume I'm seeing a virtualized NIC?

Assuming the physical NIC is still good, is there a way to fix this? I don't see anyway to revert back to the Broadcom NIC from the host and all connectivity to the box is toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear with me, Im writing this on my phone and dont have a machine in front of me to confirm this exactly...

Your physical NIC is fine.  You should have used bridged networking, not external.  Hyper-V "external" allows you to allocate physical NICs for *sole* use of a virtual machine, rather than using a virtual NIC that shares a physical one.  This is useful for bandwidth allocation or segregating a VM to a different network from the host.

The "virtual office NIC" is your broadcom NIC.  All NICs can be renamed in Windows, which makes them easier to identify.

You should just be able to delete the NIC from the Hyper-V VM, or change its type.  Worst case, remove it from the device manager and rescan for it.  One of those should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Keltari. I appreciate your efforts -- from a phone no less! I'll have to give this a try tonight. Keep in mind I'm running Hyper-V Server and I only have access to the command prompt on the host. I don't think that gives me access to the device manager, does it? I did find this PowerShell Management Library: http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/. It includes routines for managing a NIC. If you are familiar with this, do you think if I select "Remove-VMNIC" and reboot, that Hyper-V (Windows) will reconfigure the NIC (via plug-and-play?)?

Comment: Again thanks Keltari. You were right, the NIC is fine. I was not able to get the host back on the network though without rebuilding the Hyper-V server from scratch. Just could not get all the ins and outs of TCP/IP networking I guess. Now I'll probably post another question here as a follow-up to your statement, "you should have used bridged networking", to see if you want to go two-for-two.